# iTerm2, nano and mouse

Tags: terminal, mouse, iterm

I'm using the nano editor inside iTerm2. I have configured various profiles for iTerm2. In my `.nanorc`, I have configured

```
set mouse
```

to get at least some rudimentary mouse support (since nano works inside the terminal and hence was not designed to work with a mouse).

However I can not place inside nano the cursor with a click of the mouse, if I start nano from my iTerm2 **default** profile. It works fine if nano is started from of my **other** iTerm2 profiles. In shells started from the other profiles, I can click anywhere inside the edited file, and the nano insertion cursor is moved to the clicked location.

With *Default* profile, I mean the one which is present after installation of iTerm2. I did modify it (terminal size, startup command), but kept it as my "default" after adding a few alternative profiles.

All profiles use the same startup command, i.e. `/bin/zsh` (but since the shell doesn't know anything about the mouse, this should not make any difference).

From this, I would conclude that there is some setting in that specific iTerm2 default profile, which causes that the mouse click action is not communicated to nano.

However, looking at the iTerm2 settings, I found that all settings related to the mouse pointer are general, and **not** profile-specific. Inside the profile tab, I didn't find an entry which possily would relate to the mouse.

Does somebody have an idea, what could cause this difference mouse behaviour between different profiles? Of course I could simply stop using the non-working profile, but I really would like to know how the behaviour I'm observing is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason:

There *is* a mouse-related section in the preferences:
It is in the `Terminal` tab and says *enable mouse reporting*.
This was unchecked in my default profile. After enabling it, everything works fine.